# Access Denied error creating Personal View in Document Library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

I am getting access denied errors when trying to create a personal view in a SharePoint 2010 library. I have no problems creating public views. I have full control access to the site and library.

Other users on the library are also experiencing this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: did you customize the Full control permissions? make sure "Manage Personal Views" option not unchecked. If you have option, then i would try to create another site collection then try it there

Comment: I can't find the setting for Manage Personal Views.  Is it in the Permission Level screen?  If it is then it is missing from mine. Thanks.